# Can't import TestBed in karma config

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Angular version 2.0.0-rc.6

In [**karma-test-shim.js** (project on github)](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/angular2-tiddle/blob/master/karma-test-shim.js#L67)

```
Promise.all([
  System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
  System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
]).then(function (providers) {
  var coreTesting = providers[0]; //undefined
  var browserTesting = providers[1]; //all right

  coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
}).then(function() {
  // Finally, load all spec files.
  // This will run the tests directly.
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
}).then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```

Experimentally it has been found that new [**/node_modules/@angular/core/testing/index.d.ts**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.6/modules/%40angular/core/testing/index.ts) don't export values.

Why I can't System.import('@angular/core/testing') but can System.import('@angular/core')?

P.S.

1.errors on **npm test**

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "stack": "karma-test-shim.js:72:14\ninvoke@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:34\nrun@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:50\nnode_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:591:61\ninvokeTask@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:43\nrunTask@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:58\ndrainMicroTaskQueue@node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:497:43\nrun@node_modules/core-js/client/core.js:4019:30\nnode_modules/core-js/client/core.js:4032:32\nflush@node_modules/core-js/client/core.js:4387:12",
    "line": 72,
    "sourceURL": "karma-test-shim.js"
  }
```

2. [this bug on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11322)

Comment: Are there no errors from SystemJS or network? How are you defining it in SystemJS configuration? Notice that for UMD bundles there is [a separate file for testing](https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.6/bundles/)

Comment: @estus, erros was added higher. I did not see any config option related to bundles in this [project](https://github.com/equalize-squad/angular2-devise-token-auth), which i use as example, should I add them? How? [My project page](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/angular2-tiddle/blob/master/karma-test-shim.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with angular 2.1.2. I managed to fix it by downgrading the systemjs version. My version of systemjs was 0.19.39 and with that it was giving undefined when importing @angular/core/testing. When downgrading to 0.19.27 it worked.